# setTimeout() function usage in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, settimeout, yarnpkg

I want use function `setTimeout()` in one of my methods in Vue.js component. If i add this:

```
setTimeout(() => alert(), 2000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(alert(), 2000);
```

I have error in console:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/modules/web.timers'

Why? It is pure javascript function right? In CLI i have:

> To install it, you can run: npm install --save core-js/modules/web.timers

But i am using `yarn` how i can find this package?

Comment: it's weird, try `yarn add core-js`

Comment: Yep it works... But why? :D Thx!

Comment: like i said it's weird since this function is a pure js function, i think the bundler doesn't refer to the pure js and it tries to get from the module `core-js`

Comment: According to https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#settimeout-and-setinterval this polyfill is applied when you are targeting IE9 and below.